# How to replace in a string by pattern

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

> 01.jpg"> 01]02.jpg"> 02]03.jpg"> 03]04.jpg"> 04]05.jpg"> 05]06.jpg"> 06]07.jpg"> 07]08.jpg"> 08]09.jpg"> 09]10.jpg"> 10]11.jpg"> 11]12.jpg"> 12]13.jpg"> 13]14.jpg"> 14]15.jpg"> 15]16.jpg"> 16]17.jpg"> 17]18-19.jpg"> 18-19]20.jpg"> 20

As a result I want to only have:

> 01.jpg#02.jpg#03.jpg#04.jpg    ... until 20.jpg

So I need to replace  `"> (.*)]`   by `#`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Using `whats the code I need` sounds demanding, your question would have been fine without that.

Answer (score 2):

You have an almost working pattern to use with `preg_replace()`. Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/"> \d+\]?/', '#', $string);
```

- `\d+` is digit one or more times
- `]` needs to be escaped with `\`
- `?` makes the `]` optional

An alternate pattern would be `/"> [^\]]+\]?/`.